# RegEx - First Hypen Only

Tags: regex

I have a requirement to remove duplicate hyphens or simply remove them if they are not the first character on the string.  I would like to use a regular expression 'replace' in Java script.  I have fought with it for several hours.  When I think I have it, in the end all hyphens are removed.  Even the first one.  Below is an example of the request.

Example: 1a-1-1    Result:  1a11 
Example: -1-1b-1-  Result: -11b1
Example: ---1c11-  Result: -1c11

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/HJsBn7/1

Answer (score 0):

Use line start, it'll [take](https://regexr.com/4v22i) only first hyphen.

```
^-
```

Comment: Zaven, Thanks for the response. I want to keep 'only' the hyphen in position 1 if it exists and strip any other hyphens if they are entered. If there is not a hyphen in the position 1 then strip them all.  It is not a duplicate.  Their example uses a look-behind.  I do not believe JavaScript supports look-behind assertions.